# What is the option to remove LIVE label beside the timer in VideoJS?

Tags: vue.js, video.js

Here is the object of `options` I'm passing.

I'm running this on Vue 3 Composition API. LIVE label doesn't show up with plain HTML file though. With VueJS the LIVE label is showing up. Here is the image reference

[image]

```
  const options = {
                    'autoplay': true,
                    'controls': true,
                    'liveui': false,
                    'controlBar': {
                        'liveDisplay': false,
                        'pictureInPictureToggle': false,
                        'muteToggle': false,
                    }, 

                    'sources': [{
                      'src': 'https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
                      'type': 'video/mp4'
                    }]

                  }

      player.value = videojs(videoPlayer.value, options, function onPlayerReady() {
                          console.log('onPlayerReady>>>>>>>');
                      })
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

Had to add `'seekToLive': false` inside `controlBar` object.

Here is my final options object

```
const options = {
                    'autoplay': true,
                    'controls': true,
                    'liveui': false,
                    'controlBar': {
                        'liveDisplay': false,
                        'pictureInPictureToggle': false,
                        'muteToggle': false,
                        'seekToLive': false 
                    }, 
                    'sources': [{
                      'src': 'https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
                      'type': 'video/mp4'
                    }]
                  }
```